# TinyMCE and Jsp

Tags: tinymce

How to set tinymce only font arial in the editor when copying and pasting over tinymce with other fonts?

When copying and pasting on this editor I need to unpack the font of the text that they bring and remain only in the Arial font, the above because when generating a pdf with different fonts from Arial it produces an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.